# DataTable Row being Overwritten

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I'm trying to make a Sharepoint form that adds rows to a GridView in Visual C#. I can only write the first row however - when I click AddRow - it just overwrites the last row I inputted. I have attempted using sessions and Page.IsPostBack, but Sharepoint just dies when I try and run it. Thanks!

namespace VisualWebPartProject3.VisualWebPart1
{
    public partial class VisualWebPart1UserControl : UserControl
    {
        DataTable dt;

```
    private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        //{
        dt = new DataTable();
        CreateDataTableColumns(dt);
        //  }
    }

    private void CreateDataTableColumns(System.Data.DataTable dt)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("Title");
        dt.Columns.Add("Type");
    }



    protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void AddRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string title = txtTitle.Text;
        string selection = selectionList.Text;


        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        //addrows
        dr["Title"] = title;
        dr["Type"] = selection;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        int count = dt.Rows.Count;
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        countTxt.Text = count.ToString();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure if Sharepoint is like web forms, but if it is, every time you click the AddRow button, it instantiate the page (component/UserControl) and triggers all life cycle of the page and it includes the Page_Load event, so every time the button is clicked, you are creating a new DataTable and you'll ever get only one row. You need to store the DataTable in a session or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep track of the total rows in a Session or Viewstate. Then load the items from Viewstate and add the next row.
Take a look at the snippet below so see it in action.

```
protected void AddRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    //check if the viewstate exists
    if (ViewState["myTable"] != null)
    {
        //cast the viewstate back to a datatable
        dt = ViewState["myTable"] as DataTable;
    }
    else
    {
        //add columns to tne new datatable
        dt.Columns.Add("Title");
        dt.Columns.Add("Type");

        //add the table to the viewstate
        ViewState["myTable"] = dt;
    }

    string title = "title " + dt.Rows.Count;
    string selection = "selection " + dt.Rows.Count;

    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Title"] = title;
    dr["Type"] = selection;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```